# How do I call help if path undefined using OptionParser?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and am trying to code an elegant method for setting the working directory for the program. All file accesses with be relative to this path.

The program may or may not be run from within a Git repo. I also want to provide a method of overriding the path.

I'm using OptionParser and am having difficulty getting it to set the option correctly.  It seems that `work_area` always gets set to the Git toplevel, regardless of whether or not I'm using the `--work_area` flag.  I've tried using a `||` operator within the `opts.on` and that didn't work either.

```
options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner =  "Usage: mysprogram.rb [options]"

  options[:work_area] = `git rev-parse --show-toplevel --quiet 2>/dev/null`
  opts.on("-d", "--work_area", String, "Override default work area.") do |wa|
    options[:work_area] = wa
  end
  if options[:work_area]
    puts "Work area is " + options[:work_area]
  else
    puts "ERROR: Valid work directory not found or specified."
    puts opts
    exit
  end

  opts.on_tail("-h", "--help", "Show this message") do
    puts opts
    exit
  end
end.parse!
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong, or how to make this more Ruby-like, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block you pass to `opts.on("-d" ...)` is called *after* the block that's passed to `OptionParser.new`, so your `puts` statement is being executed before the argument parsing is actually happening. Try initializing it to the default (and testing it) outside of the `OptionParser.new` block entirely:

```
options = {}
opts = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner =  "Usage: mysprogram.rb [options]"

  opts.on("-d", "--work_area", String, "Override default work area.") do |wa|
    options[:work_area] = wa
  end

  opts.on_tail("-h", "--help", "Show this message") do
    puts opts
    exit
  end
end
opts.parse!

# Notice the "||=" here; this means "set options[:work_area] to a new thing 
# only if it's not nil or false."
options[:work_area] ||= `git rev-parse --show-toplevel --quiet 2>/dev/null`

if options[:work_area]
  puts "Work area is " + options[:work_area]
else
  puts "ERROR: Valid work directory not found or specified."
  puts opts
  exit
end
```

Comment: puts opts isn't working because it's outside of the parser do/end.  I'm trying puts options[:help] but that results in "nil".  Any thoughts?

Comment: That's because of a copy and paste error on my end. This should be a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used something like:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.banner = "Usage: #{ File.basename($0) } [options]"
  opt.on('--path PATH') { |o| options[:path] = o }
  options[:help] = opt.help
end.parse!

puts options[:help] if !options[:path]
```

Saving that and running it with a `--path foo` option returns no output, as it should.

Running it without the `--path foo` option outputs:

```
Usage: test.rb [options]
        --path PATH
```

Also, notice that OptionParser automatically supplies a `-h` or `--help` parameter for you if you don't define them. Calling the same code with `-h` results in the output you'd expect and are trying to code into your script.

Comment: -h throws an ambiguous option error so I had to add it to the parser.

--help works without the addition.  I also noticed that I was coding these as boolean flags and not ARGV that would accept strings e.g. "--path" versus "--path PATH" or "--path [PATH]" since I want this to be optional.

Comment: I'm trying to puts options[:help] and that returns nil.  I've tried commenting out my re-definition of help and am getting the same result.  Any ideas?